# Using sed in a bash script to replace text in file

Tags: bash, file, sed

On Mac OS X it is possible for an administrator to unlock the screensaver of another administrator by modifying the file located at:
`/etc/pam.d/screensaver`.

I need a simple command to change this file (my script is performing many other actions, and I am already running the bash script as sudo). This may have already been changed, so I need to test for the string and change if found.

In the file is the string

> account    **required**       pam_group.so no_warn deny group=admin,wheel ruser fail_safe

I need to change this to

> account    **sufficient**       pam_group.so no_warn deny group=admin,wheel ruser fail_safe

Ideally I'd like to report if the change was necessary, or had already been made before my script was run.

I could also merely comment out or remove the line, I'd prefer to change it as detailed.
This TN details what I'm attempting

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5145?viewlocale=en_US

Comment: Also, the white space between "account    required       pam_group.so" or "account    sufficient       pam_group.so" may vary (could be a TAB or one or more space characters) depending on who in my team may have modified it in the past

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat foo
foo bar
account    required       pam_group.so no_warn deny group=admin,wheel ruser fail_safe
account    required       am_group.so no_warn deny group=admin,wheel ruser fail_safe
accoi    required       pam_group.so no_warn deny group=admin,wheel ruser fail_
foo bar

$ awk '$1~/^account$/ && $3~/^pam_group.so/ && $2~/^required$/ { $2 = "sufficient" }1' foo
foo bar
account sufficient pam_group.so no_warn deny group=admin,wheel ruser fail_safe
account    required       am_group.so no_warn deny group=admin,wheel ruser fail_safe
accoi    required       pam_group.so no_warn deny group=admin,wheel ruser fail_
foo bar
```

If the first column (`$1`) is `account` and the second column (`$2`) is `required` and the third column (`$3`) starts with the string `pam_group.so`, replace `required` with `sufficient` in the second column.

Answer (score 0):

`awk ' { if($2 == "required") {sub("required","sufficient");} print }' filename`  for awk solution

Answer (score -1):

try with sed command:

```
sed -i 's/old-word/new-word/g' <filename>
```